# How to use an accumulator with Java Streams with a default value?

Tags: functional-programming

I am using class2D point.

I want to write a method `furthestCoordinate` that determines the farthest point from the point `base` in a given stream and return the base itself if the stream is empty. I have written an `Comparator` which compares coordinates with the `base`, but it throws an exception when given an empty stream:

```
static Comparator<Coordinate> Comp = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Coordinate o1, Coordinate o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.distanceTo(basePoint),o2.distanceTo(basePoint));
    }
};

public static Coordinate furthestCoordinate(Stream<Coordinate> coordinateStream, Coordinate base) {
    basePoint = base; // safes the base to be accessible for the Comparator 

    return coordinateStream.max(Comp).get();
}
```

How can I use an accumulator, which gets updated whenever the next `Coordinate` in the Stream is farther away and returns 'base' itself if the Stream is empty?

Comment: What is `WayPoint`?  It isnt defined but I presume it is a Coordinate.

Comment: Why not use `Point2D` and `Math.hypot` instead of creating your own?  After all you used `Math.pow()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8 method [`Comparator.comparingDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) to define a comparator based on the method `distanceTo()` of your `Coordinate` class.

And to `base` coordinate if the given stream was empty, apply [`Optional.orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) on the `Optional` returned by `Stream.max()` operation.

```
public static Coordinate furthestCoordinate(Stream<Coordinate> coordinateStream,
                                            Coordinate base) {
    
    return coordinateStream
        .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(base::distanceTo)) // produces Optional<Coordinate>
        .orElse(base);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. I am using the JDK classes `Math` and `Point2D.Double`

Some data

```
List<Point2D> list = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(
                new Point2D.Double(2.0, 10.0),
        new Point2D.Double(5.0, 6.0),
        new Point2D.Double(4.0, 9.3)));
        
Point2D basePoint = new Point2D.Double(0., 0.);
```

A defined comparator.

```
Comparator<Point2D> distanceComp = Comparator
        .comparingDouble(point -> Math.hypot(basePoint.getX() - point.getX(),
                basePoint.getY() - point.getY()));
```

And the stream.

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(distanceComp))
        .ifPresentOrElse(point->System.out.println("Max point is " + point),
                () -> System.out.println("Empty stream"));
```

prints

```
Max point is Point2D.Double[2.0, 10.0]
```

[Collectors.maxBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)) returns an `Optional<Point2D.Double>`.  So using [IfPresentOrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)) can handle the answer or report an empty stream.

If you prefer to use your own classes and methods for the point and distance   then the above should still work just fine.

Here is a function to get a comparator for a specific `basePoint`.

```
static Function<Point2D, Comparator<Point2D>> getComparator = base -> Comparator
            .comparingDouble(point -> Math.hypot(base.getX() - point.getX(),
                    base.getY() - point.getY()));
```

You can then call your method with a `stream` and the `basePoint`.

```
public static Point2D furthestCoordinate(Stream<Point2D> coordinateStream,
         Point2D basePoint) {

     return coordinateStream
             .collect(Collectors.maxBy(getComparator.apply(basePoint)))
             .orElse(basePoint);
}
```

**Note:** In this case I returned the `basePoint` for an empty stream. But any point could be a valid answer. You may want to just return the `optional` and the use `ifPresent` or someother supported method to best determine how to handle an empty stream.